# karma server exit process with code 1 in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, jasmine, gulp, karma-runner, visual-studio-cordova

i've followed this instructions to run Karma Server from Gulp task runner.

https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Visual-Studio-Tools-for-Apache-Cordova/Using-Karma-and-Jasmine-To-Test-Apache-Cordova-Apps-in-Visual-Studio-2015

When I run the task in visual studio task runner explorer I always get "process terminated with code 1".

¿How I can get more detailed info about why is not launching karma server and executing test?

packages.config:

```
{
    "name": "CordovaAngularJS",
    "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "karma": "^0.13.21",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1"
  }
}
```

gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var server = require("karma").Server;

    gulp.task('tdd', function (done) {
        new server({
            configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js'
        }, done).start();
    });
    gulp.task('default', ['tdd']);
```

karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function config() {
    config.set({
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        files: [
            'www/notAngularJS/**/*.js',
            'test/**/*js'
        ]
    });
}
```

The test file and calculator file:
root/test/calculator.js

```
describe("Calculator Jasmine", function () {

    var calculator;
    beforeEach(function () {
        //TODO: Instance calculator service
        calculator = new Calculator();
    });

    it("can add", function () {
        expect(calculator.Add(5, 5)).toEqual(10);
    });

    it ("can substract", function () {
        expect(calculator.Substract(10, 5).toEqual(5));
    });

    it("can divide", function () {
        expect(calculator.Substract(10, 2).toEqual(5));
    });

    it("can multiply", function () {
        expect(calculator.Substract(10, 5).toEqual(50));
    });
});
```

root/www/notAngularJS/calculator.js:

```
function Calculator() {

}

Calculator.prototype.Add = Add;
Calculator.prototype.Substract = Substract;
Calculator.prototype.Divide = Divide;
Calculator.prototype.Multiply = Multiply;

function Add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

function Substract(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}

function Divide(a, b) {
    return a / b;
}

function Multiply(a, b) {
    return a * b;
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

I finally decided to use Grunt that is supported too in Visual Studio 2015 instead of Gulp. With grunt all is working fine.

[KarmaGruntJSUnit Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KarmaGruntJSUnit.MSBuild/)